# Does github enterprise server installed on Vmware supports Oauth?

Tags: github, github-api

Does github enterprise server installed on Vmware supports Oauth app integration?. Kindly, share any docs related to it.

Answer (score 1):

All VM images of GitHub Enterprise Server support the same functionality since they're all the same code.  You can see the docs for GitHub Apps and OAuth Apps in [the developer section of the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/developers).  Note that that version is for GitHub Enterprise Server 3.6, but you can choose a different version from the drop-down in the top right corner.